# NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule) When Testing in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, frontend, angular2-services

I'm brand new to Angular2 and trying to write a test in the `app.component.spec.ts` file. My application is relatively simple, besides the fact that it imports LoginComponent and LogoutComponent from a 3rd party library (written by coworkers). The components are used in a route login or logout respectively right now, pretty simple stuff. Running `ng serve` compiles ok and the application runs "smoothly". Running `ng test`, however, gives me this error:

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[LogoutComponent -> SessionService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[LogoutComponent -> SessionService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for SessionService!
```

LogoutComponent is imported from a different project. Does this error mean I need to go into that project and make some changes, or am I supposed to be mocking SessionService somehow in my project?

Spec code:

```
import {} from 'jasmine';
import {async, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {AuthErrorStateService, LogoutComponent} from '@custom-library';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {AppErrorStateService} from './core/error-states/app-error-state.service';
import {TopNavComponent} from './core/top-nav/top-nav.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed
        .configureTestingModule({
          imports: [RouterTestingModule],
          providers: [
            AppErrorStateService, AuthErrorStateService
          ],
          declarations: [AppComponent, TopNavComponent, LogoutComponent],
        })
        .compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'My App'`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('My App');
  });

  it('should render title in a h1 tag', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toEqual('Welcome to My App!');
  });
});
```

Comment: Would help to see your `TestBed` configuration, but it looks like you didn't put `SessionService` in the `providers` array of the config object.

Comment: Hi, try to add provider to providers array in spec.ts file.

Comment: @TheHeadRush If you're talking about the `TestBed` config object, I didn't - because `SessionService` is not defined at all within the project. It's defined in the project LogoutComponent is being imported from.

Comment: @JosefKatič The provider (SessionService) is not from within this project - it's from another. If I import it into this project and put it in providers array, Karma just yells that the next service is not being provided (SessionServiceApi) and so on and so on.

Comment: @RyanSperzel Could you please send here the test (spec.ts) code?

Comment: @JosefKatič I just included it above

Comment: Your setup instantiates multiple components. You either either need to add all the services injected into`TopNavComponent` and `LogoutComponent` to the providers array (making it an integration test), or remove the extra components from `declarations` and add `schema: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` to the config.

Comment: @TheHeadRush I ended up going with the CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA until I find a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: @RyanSperzel I expanded my comment into an answer, if you'd like to accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is declaring multiple components in `TestBed` like so

```
 declarations: [AppComponent, TopNavComponent, LogoutComponent]
```

results in multiple components being instantiated when the test calls `compileComponents()`. When that happens, each component in the `declarations` array needs its dependencies declared in the `providers` array to complete instantiation. One of the declared components depends on `SessionService`, but that service is not present in providers, so you get the `NullInjectorError`.

There are two solutions to this:

- only declare one component in the `declarations` array and add
  `schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]` to the `TestBed` configuration
  object
- continue to declare multiple components and add all the
  dependencies (or a mock thereof) for each component to the
  `providers` array

Comment: In my case, I was missing a service as well. I think the generic answer to this question is you're probably missing a service.

Comment: Bad that this error doesn't show witch service or provider is missed. In a big component it's messy to find the correct one.

Comment: @Experimenter Angular 9 does actually supply the dependence chain and identifies the problematic provider.

Comment: @TheHeadRush any example?

Comment: my problem was solved by using @Input for receiving a data object from the component that was the reason for this problem.